# Prolog - How to check if a list contains a certain item

Tags: prolog

Assume that I have a list M = [[1/4, 2/2, 3/5, 4/3, 5/1], [1/3, 2/5, 3/2, 4/4, 5/1], [1/5, 2/3, 3/1, 4/4, 5/2], [1/4, 2/1, 3/3, 4/5, 5/2], [1/5, 2/2, 3/4, 4/1, 5/3], [1/1, 2/4, 3/2, 4/5, 5/3], [1/2, 2/5, 3/3, 4/1, 5/4], [1/1, 2/3, 3/5, 4/2, 5/4], [1/3, 2/1, 3/4, 4/2, 5/5], [1/2, 2/4, 3/1, 4/3, 5/5]].

I only want to return a list of lists that contain a certain item, e.g., 3/5.

I tried writing a function that looks like:

```
include([X/Y|Rest],I,J):-
    X=:=I,
    Y=:=J,
    include(Rest,I,J).

pick([Item|Rest],I,J,Final):-
    include(Item,I,J),
    pick(Rest,I,J,[Item|R]).
```

so that I can query pick(M,3,5,F) so that F contains lists that has 3/5 in it. The function I wrote doesn't work properly, can you help me fix it?

Comment: If you want to check if a list contains a member, use `memberchk/2`. so `memberchk(I/J, Item)` succeeds if `I/J` is in the list `Item`. Your `include/3` predicate has no base case, and attempt to ensure that *every* element of the given list is `I/J`, so it will always fail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As lurker said, use member and don't forget the base case.

```
foo([],_,F).
foo([H|T],Item,[H|F]):-
    member(Item, H),
    foo(T,Item,F).
foo([_|T],Item,F) :-
    foo(T,Item,F).
```